# Add Filter for GeoJson group

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working on Leaflete, I have a featureGroup containing several feature var cicList=L featureGroup, each feature has the fields (name, epoch, year, day, length)

I would like to know how I can create a filter to add to the map only the layers with epoch 2021 and year 2022, and you must add by clicking the epoch button (2021-22)

for now thanks.

I've already tried to work with if and for cycles to go through the array in search of the satisfactory conditions, it didn't work.
I tried .forEach to no avail.
I believe I am doing something wrong.
so I hope your help to overcome this dilemma

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a function to your button that will clear your group and adds a new layer with a filter condition. For example:

```
function filterData(){
    markers.clearLayers();
    let filteredData = new L.GeoJSON(loadedData, {
        onEachFeature: oef, 
        pointToLayer: ptl,
        filter: function(feature) {
            if(feature.properties['epoch'] == '2021' && feature.properties['year'] == '2022'){
                return true;
            }
        }
     }).addTo(markers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to modify the function you sent me but it's giving me problems, the filter doesn't filter and the map disappears from the screen when I add the function

```
var ciclList = L.layerGroup([DaisyLData, .....])


 lnk6162.addEventListener("click", function (feature,layers) {
                markers.clearLayers();
                let filteredData = new L.GeoJSON(loadedData, {
                    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.NAME+' ('+feature.properties.year+')');}, 
                    pointToLayer: ptl,
                    filter: function(feature) {
                        if(feature.properties.SEASON == '2021' && feature.properties.year == '2022'){
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                 }).addTo(markers);
            
          
     });
```